# Why doesn't this program produce any warning?

Tags: c, linux, warnings, mips

```
#include<stdio.h>
void jigar (int ji)
{
    printf("%d",ji);
}
void main()
{
int a=32;
(jigar)(a);
}
```

When I run this program with the -Wall option, the compiler doesn't give any warning or error, it works fine. But when I compile this program in **MIPS cross-compiler tool chain**, then it gives an error:

```
(jigar)(a);
```

at this line. Now my question is: why gcc for linux doesn't point out my silly mistake?

Comment: try using -ansi -pedantic flags also.

Comment: What error does the MIPS compiler give you?

Comment: @ reader_1000  your flag also not showing that error

Comment: -ansi -pedantic ensures that code is ansi compliant. Therefore there might be a problem with MIPS compiler, however I am not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with `(jigar)(a);` as it is acceptable in standard C. The reason your MIPS compiler gives warning is because perhaps that compiler does not fully implement standard C.

Edit: Regarding Als's request for why this is standard C, here's how:

Look at the ISO C grammar here: http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~mckeeman/cs48/mxcom/doc/notation/c.html and note that a function call

```
postfix-expression -> postfix-expression ( )
                    | postfix-expression ( argument-expression-list )
```

can have `postfix-expression` as function. There is a rule that says:

```
postfix-expression -> primary-expression
```

where `primary-expression` could be an `identifier`, that is function name. However there is also this rule:

```
primary-expression -> ( expression )
```

and if you follow the chain of rules from `expression` you get back at `primary-expression` again. Therefore indirectly, you have:

```
primary-expression -> ... -> ( primary-expression ) -> ( identifier )
```

The semantics of C indicates that `( expression )` has the same type and value as `expression` (1). According to the grammar, (jigar)(a) is correct. Semantically, `(jigar)` and `jigar` have the same type and value. Therefore C accepts `(jigar)(a)` and the functionality is the same as `jigar(a)`.

Edit 2:

(1) C99 draft section 6.5.1 article 5:

> A parenthesized expression is a primary expression. **Its type and value are identical to those of the unparenthesized expression**. **It is** an lvalue, **a function designator**, or a void expression **if the unparenthesized expression is**, respectively, an lvalue, **a function designator**, or a void expression.

P.S. anyone knows where I can get the documentation for ISO C, like a list of features or something? I have seen people quote it, but I couldn't find it myself.

Comment: Perhaps You should back up `as it is acceptable in standard C`. by a Quote from the Standard. Just because it works or you use it all the time does not provide evidence that it is accepted by the standard.

Comment: @Shahbaz: you can download the freely available [C99 Draft](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) and [C1x Draft](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf) (both in PDF format) from the "official home of JTC1/SC22/WG14 - C" (or the "international standardization working group for the programming language C").

Comment: +1 Because this answers the Question now. Just because GCC compiles it ,could not be an answer(OP already states that observed behavior).Given that the answer should explicitly say/prove how the construct is standard compliant and nothing better than quoting the standard itself, which leaves no doubt whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

> why **(jigar)(a);** does not give warning or error?

That's a perfectly acceptable construct for a Standard C conformant compiler (which I'm not claiming `gcc` is).
That's just a pair of extra redundant parenthesis around the function name, resolving to the same thing as the function name by itself ... or surrounded by even more parenthesis.

```
/* assuming `jigar` is a honest-to-God function
** all 3 statements below "do" the same thing */
jigar(a);
(jigar)(a);
(((((((jigar)))))))(a);
```

I've seen it used in real-life to prevent macro expansion (the example was made up right now though).

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MACRO(x) ((x) - 42)

int (MACRO)(int x) { return 42 + x; } /* does not expand MACRO! */

int main(void) {
    printf(" MACRO  ==> %d\n", MACRO(100));   /* expand */
    printf("(MACRO) ==> %d\n", (MACRO)(100)); /* do not expand */
    return 0;
}
```

*You can see the code above running on [codepad](http://codepad.org/QZi8cc67) and on [ideone](http://ideone.com/HbyCr).*

**And `main` returns `int`, not `void`.**

Comment: Perhaps You should back up `that's a perfectly acceptable construct for a Standard C conformant compiler.` by a Quote from the Standard. Just because it works or you use it all the time does not provide evidence that it is accepted by the standard.

Comment: @Als: after the preprocessing stage having the parenthesis is a "no-op" like the parenthesis in `return (7 - (6));`. You can have a look at 6.5.2.2 in [n1256.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) for constraints and semantics of function calls.

Comment: If you state this is standard c, then you should prove `how?` it is standard c, by using the standard as reference or by deducing the example quoted to a point where it is clearly inferrable to the standard.Just because gcc allows it is not enough evidence of it being standard c.

Comment: My reference to `gcc` is just to provide a context for the answer to the question "... why gcc for linux doesn't point out ...?" Other than that (and the implied assumption that `gcc` is a Standard conformant compiler) I have no use for `gcc` in my answer. I fail to see why you think a quote from the Standard is necessary to "prove" that `(jigar)(a)` is just as Standard as `(((((((jigar)))))))(a)` or `jigar(a)`. And I'm not going to try and fish out of the Standard the rules about extra redundant parenthesis.

Comment: Check your answer again, It only says the construct is valid because GCC compiles it.And you use it often.GCC is standard compliant but your blind faith on it would imply that GCC cannot have any bugs(which is not true).You neither stated any explanation about parenthesis(which you do now)or why it is valid and how it applies here. Given that your answer is useless, the comments are **now**useful, I suggest, you add that to your answer.Never debated your answer was incorrect,just didn't agree the basis on which you base your answer for saying the construct is valid.

Comment: Thank you @Als. I mostly agree with you :)

Comment: Now you earn my +1 for answering it in an convincing way :)

Answer (score 1):

The only error that I see in your code is that your `main` returns `void`, whereas [it should return `int`](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/newbie.html#faq-29.3).

`gcc 4.4.3` with `-Wall` picks this up.

If you're referring to the parentheses around `(jigar)`, it's valid C. If your MIPS compiler doesn't like it, then it's a problem with the MIPS compiler.

Comment: Perhaps You should back up `it's valid C`. by a Quote from the Standard. Just because it works or you use it all the time does not provide evidence that it is accepted by the standard.